# Multiple Google.GData.Documents.DocumentService.Query() requests get stuck

Tags: c#

When I execute DocumentsService.Query(oDocQuery) multiple times, it seems to hang.

```
 where

 oDocQuery = new DocumentsListQuery
                ("https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full?xoauth_requestor_id=" + p_User);
```

Can `DocumentService.Query()` access multiple users synchronously?

Comment: Not to be argumentative, but I can't believe that edits can be 'accepted' that don't even address fundamental grammar and formatting issues.

Comment: You don't understand my question

Comment: That comment wasn't directed at you, or meant to be an insult to the quality of your question. I apologize for that misunderstanding. StackOverflow welcomes questions from non-English speakers and there is a decent sized group of editors who enjoy 'anglifying' those questions. One problem this site has however, not just with questions from non-English speakers, is that seemingly trivial, nondescript edits are accepted by our edit review team in the face of glaring issues with grammar, formatting, and other fixable problems. Your question is fine for this site (I reviewed it myself).

Comment: But there were two previous 'edits' which did not, as far as I could tell, address the major issues with the question's grammar, formatting, and clarity. Yet these edits were accepted quite blissfully. Sorry for the rant. Enjoy your first upvote.